# Having trouble with a procedure in MariaDB

Tags: sql, database, transactions, mariadb, procedure

I'm creating a basic airport management system SQL database using MariaDB. I want to create a procedure containing a transaction that makes sure that:
Whenever a passenger is moved to another flight, the luggage associated with (belonging to) that passenger, is transferred to that same flight. I keep getting the error code:

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Flight_ID' in 'field list'

Where's the error? Here's my code for the procedure along with the relevant tables from the database:

[Code for the procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbJXP.png)

[Tables referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQWk3.png)

The procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE PassengerTransfer (
    IN vPassportNo VARCHAR(9), vOldFlightID VARCHAR(4), vNewFlightID VARCHAR(4), OUT vStatus VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    UPDATE TRAVELS
    SET Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
    WHERE Flight_ID = vOldFlightID AND Passport_no = vPassportNo;

    UPDATE CARRIES INNER JOIN LUGGAGE ON LUGGAGE.LuggageID = CARRIES.LuggageID
    SET CARRRIES.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
    WHERE LUGGAGE.Passport_no = vPassportNo;

    IF (TRAVELS.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID AND TRAVELS.Passport_no = vPassportNo)
    AND (CARRIES.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID AND LUGGAGE.LuggageID = CARRIES.LuggageID
    AND LUGGAGE.Passport_no = vPassportNo)
        THEN SET vStatus = "Trasaction PassengerTransfer committed!"; COMMIT;
        ELSE SET vStatus = "Transaction PassengerTransfer rollback"; ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

The tables referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE Travels(
Passport_no varchar(9) not null,
Flight_ID varchar(4) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Passport_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Flight_ID) REFERENCES Flight(Flight_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (Passport_no) REFERENCES Passenger(Passport_no) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Luggage(
LuggageID       varchar(5) not null,
Weight          decimal(4,2),                   
Passport_no     varchar(9) not null, 
PRIMARY KEY (LuggageID),
FOREIGN KEY(Passport_no) REFERENCES Passenger(Passport_no) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Carries(
LuggageID       varchar(5) not null,
Flight_ID   varchar(4) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (LuggageID)
);
```

Comment: Copy and paste the code. (We want it here.)

Comment: I don't think that is a valid way to decide whether to `COMMIT` -- You are working with a snapshot of the data, so the value will necessarily be set.  You need to check for errors after each `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NEW` and `OLD` keywords are available only in triggers, not in procedures. So code like this:

```
UPDATE TRAVELS SET NEW.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
WHERE OLD.Flight_ID = vOldFlightID AND Passport_no = vPassportNo;
```

should be written as:

```
UPDATE TRAVELS 
SET Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
WHERE Flight_ID = vOldFlightID AND Passport_no = vPassportNo;
```

Your code:

```
UPDATE CARRIES SET NEW.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
WHERE LUGGAGE.LuggageID = CARRIES.LuggageID AND
LUGGAGE.Passport_no = vPassportNo;
```

should be written as:

```
UPDATE CARRIES 
   INNER JOIN LUGGAGE ON LUGGAGE.LuggageID=CARRIES.LuggageID
SET CARRIES.Flight_ID = vNewFlightID
WHERE LUGGAGE.Passport_no = vPassportNo;
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes but it still gives me the exact same error code... :/

Comment: Did you change the rest of the code? You do not need to check the changes you have made to the database. If there is an error the procedure will fail.

Comment: I removed the NEW. and OLD. prefixes and rewrote the two blocks of code that you pointed out. It's as though it doesn't recognize that attribute Flight_ID that I'm referencing to.

Comment: Remove the `IF`-clause. As said, you do not need to check the changes you made and the code syntax is incorrect.

Comment: But the idea of having the transaction inside the procedure is to make sure that the transfers of the passenger and the associated luggage happen "as one entity". So if, for example, the database (hypothetically) crashes, before the second update statement concerning the luggage, then the whole transaction should be rolled back. So I need a way to check if both update statements have been executed. Right? Or does SQL already know to rollback if interrupted, because the update statements are written inside the scope of a transaction?

Where is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: If something (like a crash) happens between the two updates, database will roll back the transaction automatically. You do not need to check it yourself.

Comment: Works now that I removed the IF-clause 
So, is the "start transaction" even necessary?

Comment: The transaction guarantees that the two updates work atomically (both succeed or fail), without it one of them can work and another fail.